# JS: Send custom params to event listener callbacks that can be removed without memory leaks

Tags: javascript

I have custom event listeners set up like this

```
const addListener = (callback) => {
    window.addEventListener('customEventName', (e) => {
        callback(...e.detail);
    });
};

dispatchEvent(
    new CustomEvent('customEventName', {
        detail: ['custom', 'params'],
    })
);
```

This works, but the problem arises when I try to `removeEventListener`. Because I am passing a new arrow function to `addEventListener`, I lose the reference to remove it causing a memory leak. At the same time I need the arrow function to pass custom params to the callback. I do not want the callback to receive a `CustomEvent` object as an argument to avoid property drilling (i.e. having to type `e.detail[0]` to get the first custom param. It's ugly and unnecessary).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the subscriber pattern:

```js
const subscribe = (callback) => {
  const fn = ({detail}) => void callback(...detail);
  window.addEventListener('customEventName', fn);
  return () => window.removeEventListener('customEventName', fn);
};

const cb = (...detail) => console.log(...detail);

const unsubscribe = subscribe(cb);
// will log on dispatched events
unsubscribe();
// will no longer log on dispatched events
```

Demo:

```js
const subscribe = (callback) => {
  const fn = ({detail}) => void callback(...detail);
  window.addEventListener('customEventName', fn);
  return () => window.removeEventListener('customEventName', fn);
};

const cb = (...detail) => console.log(new Date().toISOString(), ...detail);
let unsubscribe = () => {};

document.querySelector('button.dispatch').addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('customEventName', {detail: ['arg1', 'arg2']}));
});

document.querySelector('button.subscribe').addEventListener('click', () => {
  unsubscribe();
  console.log('unsubsribed');
  unsubscribe = subscribe(cb);
  console.log('subscribed');
});

document.querySelector('button.unsubscribe').addEventListener('click', () => {
  unsubscribe();
  console.log('unsubsribed');
});
```

```html
<button class="dispatch">dispatch</button>
<button class="subscribe">subscribe</button>
<button class="unsubscribe">unsubscribe</button>
```

---

> I do not want the callback to receive a `CustomEvent` object as an argument to avoid property drilling (i.e. having to type `e.detail[0]` to get the first custom param. It's ugly and unnecessary).

If you use [destructuring syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), it's actually very readable:

```js
const cb = (ev) => {
  const [arg1, arg2 /* etc. */] = ev.detail;

  // Or:
  // const {detail: [arg1, arg2 /* etc. */]} = ev;

  // Do something with args...
}
```

Comment: Note `const fn = ({detail}) => void callback(...detail);` is the same as `const fn = ({detail}) => { callback(...detail); };`